# NGINX: unknown directive "stream" how to restart nginx to add this module?

Tags: webserver, nginx

I installed nginx using `apt-get` in Linux 14.04 and have added the following to its config file:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 8443;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 1m;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:9070;
    }
}
```

There was a point on the tutorial I used:

> N.B. Need nginx build with --with-stream options.

From searching, it seems possible to enable it when building nginx from code.

Is there another way to do that with the current version I got from `apt-get`?

If not, how I could download the source and make it without losing the current configuration for my virtual hosts?